# Optimize a WHERE IN condition using an index

Tags: mysql, database-design, index-tuning

I have a table that looks like the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( 
    type       TINYINT,    -- low cardinality (2..5)
    id         BINARY(16), -- high cardinality
    other_data OTHERTYPE(n),
    CONSTRAINT foo_PK PRIMARY KEY (type, id)
);
```

One application accessing the database that contains that table runs point queries by `type` and `id`, and queries that filter by multiple `(type, id)` pairs.

The question is: What index would perform better in these cases? Currently, I group `type` column and do `UNION` on `SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = ? AND id IN (?)`

The rule of thumb to use the highest cardinality column first would still work best, or should I define a `(type, id)` index?

*Note: The database is running on top of MySQL, but answers considering other RDBMSs would be interesting too.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Caveat: This answer applies to InnoDB in MySQL.  It may not apply to other MySQL Engines, nor to other RDBMSs.*

A `PRIMARY KEY` is

- Clustered with the data, and
- A uniqueness constraint, and
- An index

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = ? AND id IN (?,?,?)` is best handled by `PRIMARY KEY(type, id)` with the columns in that order.  (Second best is `INDEX(type, id)`).

- Being an index, the lookup does not need to scan the entire table.
- Being clustered, the lookup *and* the `*` (of `SELECT *`) are done at the same time.
- Being unique is not relevant to this `SELECT`.
- The column order is required because the `=` must come first.
- If there is only one item in the `IN`, the `IN` will be optimized to `=`; the index is still optimal.

Cardinality of `type` versus `id` is, contrary to a well entrenched wives' tale, irrelevant, at least for this query.

Side note:  The order of items in the `WHERE` has no impact on performance; the order in the index does.

In this case the `=` should come first in the index, then more complex item(s), `IN` in this case.

`id` smells like a packed UUID.  For huge tables that is a terrible type of index, probably in all RDBMSs, since it is so random that caching is impractical.

[*Index Cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) for MySQL/MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your database. Many can bitmap together multiple single column indexes. If your application ALWAYS queries on those two together, I don't see the harm in having them both in one index.